# How to print preview my sinhala text from textbox?

Tags: c#

I want show print preview of my Sinhala text from textbox. In here I used print preview dialog

```
    private void printDocument2_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        string strText = this.textBox1.Text; // read string from editor window
        StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(strText, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII, false);
        int charactersOnPage = 5;
        float linesPerPage = 0;
        float yPosition = 0;
        int count = 0;
        float leftMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Left;
        float topMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Top;
        string line = null;
        Font printFont = this.textBox1.Font;
        SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        // Work out the number of lines per page, using the MarginBounds.
        linesPerPage = ev.MarginBounds.Height / printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics);
        // Iterate over the string using the StringReader, printing each line.
        while (count < linesPerPage && ((line = myReader.ReadLine()) != null))
        {
            // calculate the next line position based on the height of the font according to the printing device
            yPosition = topMargin + (count * printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics));
            // draw the next line in the rich edit control
            ev.Graphics.DrawString(line, printFont, myBrush, leftMargin, yPosition, new StringFormat());
            count++;
        }
        // If there are more lines, print another page.
        if (line != null)
            ev.HasMorePages = true;
        else
            ev.HasMorePages = false;
        myBrush.Dispose();
    }
```

This works, but my text is "අම්මා" but it show as this way අ්මමා" so please help me it show as correct way.

I want to print the contents of a TextBox, so I am trying make a PrintDocument out of the TextBox. But I dont find a way to convert a simple TextBox to a PrintDocument. Any ideas?

Comment: If you take the minimal time required to check that your code is formatted, you are much more likely to get help. Seriously, put **some** effort in.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess, based on this big mess of code, would be to specify encodings on the [streamreaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143456) (and maybe other objects that use encoding).

But, seriously, you should have cleaned up your code and made a smaller, more comprehensible, example to reproduce/demonstrate your problem. Also, variables named like `linkLabel6`, `printDialog1`, `printDocument2`, `linkLabel7` or `textBox1` don't help either.

Comment: thanx I used this new streamreaders now print preview is not visible.

Comment: ...so? Fire up the debugger! See what's going on. We're not clearvoyant! It also doesn't help that you *completely* removed your code...

Comment: Did you  take a look at what you actually did? The code is completely unreadable. At least put in some of your own effort.

Comment: Jeez; do you actually have **ANY CLUE** to what you're doing? Why would you use Encoding.ASCII for "sinhala text"? Seriously, WTF??? Hae a look at something like [UTF8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx). But if I were you, I'd first figure out what the heck [Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) is and why you need it. Read this: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)